# Interface and class inheritance. Is this an avoidable pattern?

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I'd appreciate any advice on which way to go on in the following scenario. Let's see if I can explain it clearly (english is not my native language so things might get confusing, sorry).

Suppose I have the following interfaces:

```
internal interface IBlah
{
     int Frob();
}

internal interface IBlahOnSteroids: IBlah
{
     double Duh();
}
```

Now we have a Foo class with a 'has a' relationship with an IBlah object:

```
public class Foo
{
     IBlah blah;

     internal Foo(IBlah blah)
     {
          this.blah = blah;
     }

     public int Frob()
     {
          ....
          return this.blah.Frob();
     }
}
```

Now we also need a FooOnSteroids class that has a 'has a' relationship with a IBlahOnSteroids object.
The question is, knowing that part of IBlahOnSteroids is already implemented in Foo, what happens if we create
FooOnSteroids inheriting from Foo?

We would get something like this:

```
public class FooOnSteroids: Foo
{
    IBlahOnSteroids blah;

    internal FooOnSteroids(IBlahOnSteroids blah)
        :base(blah) 
    {
         this.blah = blah;
    }

    public double Duh()
    {
         return this.blah.Duh();
    }
}
```

Is this a recommended pattern? We are passing down the inheritance chain the same 'blah' object and at each "level" we are storing it in a private
field with a 'useful' type. There is no way, that I can see, that I could store in BlahBase a protected property that
exposed one common IBlah reference to all descending classes as it would have to be of type IBlah wich would be of no use to BlahOnSteroids. Is this scenario even
recommended? Or should we just implement Foo and FooOnSteroids as independent classes with no inheritance (this would create code duplication)? Maybe its absolutely fine to do this, but it somehow feels like a hack. Is it?

The option of using generics, which would solve the problem in no time, is not possible as, yes I know it sucks, this library must target .Net 1.x platforms.

The option of just implementing BlahOnSteroids is also a possibility but it would mean that depending on the caller, we would have to throw an exception if any of
IBlahOnSteroids members was called. I dont like that.

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the duplication by making the base field available:

```
IBlah blah;
protected IBlah Blah { get { return blah; } }
```

and cast at the sub-type (since you expect your choice of `blah` to be respected):

```
public double Duh() {
    return ((IBlahOnSteroids)Blah).Duh();
}
```

You could also do something with generics on the base-type (to avoid the cast) but I'm not sure it is worth it. Note, however, that this might explode if the base-class decides to inject a decorator abound `blah` (if the decorator doesn't provide the second interface).

Comment: I was considering this exact suggestion. But the cast put me off simply because **I assume** the fact that the op's sample has only one method per interface is just for the sake of the example and the reality could be quite different with each interface exposing many methods, in this case I wonder if carrying the extra instance reference makes a real difference in the bigger picture vs. the potentially excessive casting all over the show? Of course the casts could be avoided by providing a property that returns the cast reference, which would be cleaner.

Comment: The problem I see with casting is that it already looks "ugly" (no offense intended) and it will be sprinkled all over the code (yes IFoo and IFooOnSteroids quite a few more members than 1)

Answer (score 2):

One alternative pattern is

```
public class Foo
{
    protected IBlah Blah { get; private set; }
    ...
}
public class FooOnSteroids : Foo 
{
    private new IBlahOnSteroids Blah { get { return (IBlahOnSteroids)base.Blah; } }
    ...
}
```

However, this isn't very different from your code; if you can't use generics, they're both fine.

Comment: +1 - I didn't think of using the get accessor like this. Sidenote: You might get better performance by using the `as` keyword instead of the C-style cast. `private new IBlahOnSteroids Blah { get { return (base.Blah as IBlahOnSteroids); }` since it bypasses the exception logic that C-style casts do. (Source: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpcasts.aspx )

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question about removing the inheritance between Foo and FooOnSteroids, I don't know all your reasoning, but I can try to provide some general guidance. You should consider using inheritance mainly to provide your clients the ability to use FooOnSteroids instances, but only write the code for Foo.

So, if conceptually your clients do this:

```
Foo foo = new FooOnSteroids();
foo.Frob()
```

you should keep the inheritance.

If you are creating the inheritance relationship ONLY to re-use code, I suggest you consider refactoring the classes to contain a class which provides the shared functionality. Inheritance is not the best pattern for code re-use.

Comment: Yes, definitely we can have FooOnSteriods.Frob(). Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can't use generics (which may or may not make your specific use case easier) I would personally opt for casting the `blah` member of `Foo`. Casting in C# is relatively painless:

```
public double Duh()
{
    return (this.blah as IBlahOnSteroids).Duh();
}
```

The `as` keyword in C# will evaluate to `null` if the object can't be cast into the type you requested. In the above example, if `this.blah` isn't an instance of `IBlahOnSteroids` you will get a `NullReferenceException`. You can check if an object is an instance of a type like so:

```
public double Duh()
{
    if (this.blah is IBlahOnSteroids)
        return (this.blah as IBlahOnSteroids).Duh();
    else
        throw new InvalidTypeException("Blah is not an instance of IBlahOnSteroids");
}
```

Though in the code in your original example it shouldn't be *possible* for `blah` to not be an instance of `IBlahOnSteroids` since it's assigned in the constructor, which makes that assertion at compile time for you.

Comment: The problem with casts is that it will be sprinkled all over the code (IFoo has a lot more members than 1). Thanks for the advice.